# WordPress Hero SlideShow Links

Tags: wordpress

I'm fairly new to WordPress and I'm working on a site that was created by someone else; I've inherited the entire thing. There is a Hero Slideshow which works, but users have to click on the "tabs" then click on another image (Learn More) in order to go to the page they want; which of course is too much trouble.

I've found the code in front-page.php and I've changed how the spans and a href tags are in hopes of making the "tabs" in the Hero slideshow link directly to the associated pages. Everything looks correct and if you hover over the tabs the browser will show the correct link - however when you click on the tab it simply rotates the slideshow and doesn't actually link to the associated page. I can't find where I can change this behavior.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

stay well away from the php in wordpress . 
just uninstall the hero slideshow and use "Cyclone Slider 2" plugin its very user friendly
easy to use , you can add and change pic and there is  a lot of options on movement speeds enbed url links (etc)